# Dynamic input placeholder JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to allow the user to show the position of a specific word [which will be replaced on run time only with specific data from database ] in a text area.

Example: I want to inform users about the expiry date of validity which will be different for all member's and the schedule message window contains the text area and allow user to input message.

Example: If message is something like  "Dear user as per new rules expiry-date is $date$. Thank you"

So in this message during run time i will replace $date$ with actual value from database.

```
var message= message.replace("$date$", db_value_date);
```

But user can compose the message in any order
like "$date$ is the expiry date "  or  "recharge before $date$ to avoid late fee" etc Only rule is $date$ must be present at some part of the text.

So i any way to allow the user to edit the message but not the text "$date$" but they can change its position anywhere in the text field or text area.

I can always check for the text $date$ is present in text area or not if not present i can inform user that invalid message. But the UI styling will be broken.

Comment: So you want to avoir user from deleting the word `$date$` inside your textarea ?

Comment: Yes , but they can change this to anywhere in the text area

Comment: I didn't get how the UI style will be broken.

Comment: The easiest would be to detect if the textarea contains `$data$` on validation

Comment: @Guedes Just looking how  to add styles similar to required field validation against this custom rule

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to check on validation if the textarea contains `$data$` or not

**EDIT**

The code now works with multiple textarea. The `id` of the error should be the `id` of the TextArea + "*Error*"

Add your css customization on the class `error`

```js
var error = document.getElementById("error");

function validate() {
  var textAreas = document.getElementsByClassName("specialText");
  for (var i = 0; i < textAreas.length; i++) {
    var textArea = textAreas[i];
    var text = textArea.value;
    var id = textArea.id;
    var linkedError = document.getElementById(id + "Error");
    if (text.indexOf("$data$") === -1)
      linkedError.style.visibility = "visible";
    else
      linkedError.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
First text
<br>
<textarea class="specialText" id="FirstText"></textarea>
<p id="FirstTextError" class="error">You forgot to add '$data$' in first Text</p>

Second text
<br>
<textarea class="specialText" id="SecondText"></textarea>
<p id="SecondTextError" class="error">You forgot to add '$data$' in second text</p>

Third text
<br>
<textarea class="specialText" id="ThirdText"></textarea>
<p id="ThirdTextError" class="error">You forgot to add '$data$' in third text</p>
<button onclick="validate()">Send</button>
```

Comment: Its a kind of answer that i am looking for but need customization as in my case there can be n number of text fields where we need to do this same validation . So cant keep a common "error" div this is something i have to add dynamically if needed .